# Android - CountDownTimer in ListView flickers randomly

Tags: java, android, listview

I am making listview with timers, each with different deadline depending on the database(similar to auction)

```
Time now = new Time();
now.setToNow();
now.normalize(true);
nowMillis = now.toMillis(true);
.
.

String endtime = a.get(position).get(TAG_ENDTIME);
Integer timeSecond = Integer.parseInt(endtime.substring(17, 19));
Integer timeMinute = Integer.parseInt(endtime.substring(14, 16));
Integer timeHour = Integer.parseInt(endtime.substring(11, 13));
Integer timeDay = Integer.parseInt(endtime.substring(0, 2));
Integer timeMonth = Integer.parseInt(endtime.substring(3, 5)) - 1;
Integer timeYear = Integer.parseInt(endtime.substring(6, 10));

Time future = new Time();
future.set(timeSecond, timeMinute, timeHour, timeDay, timeMonth, timeYear);
future.normalize(true);

long futureMillis = future.toMillis(true);
long interval = futureMillis - nowMillis;

new CountDownTimer(interval,1000)
{
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
    {
        Long interval = millisUntilFinished;
        int days = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) / 86400);
        int hours = (int) (((millisUntilFinished / 1000) - (days * 86400)) / 3600);
        int minutes = (int) (((millisUntilFinished / 1000) - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
        int seconds = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60);

        String countdown = String.format("%dd %dh %dm %ds", days, hours, minutes, seconds);
        holder.duration.setText(countdown);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        holder.duration.setText(TimeUp);
    }

}.start();
```

That code works almost perfectly when there is only one instance.

However the problem arise when there is several instance, around 4-5 timer running at the same time

Several/all the countdown will start to flicker, be it seconds, minutes, hours, or days.

e.g. one of my timer flicker between 27d 11h 54m 50s and 0d 23h 47m 0s

Since this occur on both on emulator and on my device, it seems to be my code's flaw, but I don't have a clue what could cause this.

I tried to change

`holder.duration.setText(countdown)` into `holder.duration.setText(millisUntilFinished)`

and the the countdown flickers between the desired duration and a huge, random number,

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use one `TimerTask` and put all your UI updates into that single timer instead running multiple `CountDownTimer`s for essentially the same job since you're already doing all the math to determine when "time is up" for any particular item, you might just run one `TimerTask` and once a second have it update everything. `CountDownTimer` is useful for a single implementation count down because it does some built-in math, etc. You're redoing all that math, so you might as well use one instance of a regular `TimerTask`.

The implementation of `CountDownTimer` relays on scheduled delays in Handler messaging. A single countdown instance is unlikely to result in any bizarre behavior, but if you have several going that all supposed to "tick" when the system clock hits each second (the time in millis ends in "000" - once a second, and all at the same time), then those handlers will all try to fire simultaneously and inevitably fail.

If the UI or other process will likely delay some of these messages, even to the point where it will "skip ticks" to catch up. Also, that means that the next message delay could be only milliseconds from the next tick (i.e. if it's supposed to check every 1000 millis, but is delayed an additional 1990 millis, then it will skip a tick and also schedule the next message for 10 millis into the future.

Comment: Cool, I didn't knew about TimerTask before. Since I have an adapter for my listview, each with different duration, how would you suggest I group all the list item's timeLeft and assign them to the timer task? I am trying to use ViewGroup, but it doesn't seem to work well. Please help

Comment: well, one approach is to use the view's tag to store the "stop time" in millis. Then when the TimerTask is called, use the "update time left" method you already wrote in your CountDownTimer. You could also track other data with a HashTable or Map (for example price, discounts, etc.) Tag is just useful for holding one little piece of info.

Comment: From the AOSP docs: Tags

Unlike IDs, tags are not used to identify views. Tags are essentially an extra piece of information that can be associated with a view. They are most often used as a convenience to store data related to views in the views themselves rather than by putting them in a separate structure.

Comment: I don't quite understand your solution, and it seems rather difficult. Can you tell me whether I could just Array the duration TextViews in the adapter, Array the long millis too, then move the countdowntimer to onCreate, and put a for(index) within the onTick, so that 1 countdown will count for all the textview?
If that's possible, how can I array a TextView? I've seen some example using resID, however since my TextViews utilize the same resource(being a List), that approach is not gonna work.

Comment: Got it! I messed up a bit with arraylist, but it works now

thanks!