# ArrayList<TextView> cannot be set

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an adapter for one listview, containing these

```
    final ViewHolder holder;
if (convertView == null) 
{
    view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.auction_list_item, parent , false);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.auction_picture_imageView);
    holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.auction_name);
    holder.seller = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.auction_seller);
    holder.time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.auction_time);
    holder.duration = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.auction_duration);
    holder.currentbid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.auction_currentbid);
    holder.buynow = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.auction_buynow);
    holder.layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.auction_item);
    holder.buynowtext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.auction_buynow_textView);

    view.setTag(holder);                    
} else 
{
    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
}

String aucend = auctionList.get(position).get(TAG_AUCTIONENDTIME);
Integer timeSecond = Integer.parseInt(aucend.substring(17, 19));
Integer timeMinute = Integer.parseInt(aucend.substring(14, 16));
Integer timeHour = Integer.parseInt(aucend.substring(11, 13));
Integer timeDay = Integer.parseInt(aucend.substring(0, 2));
Integer timeMonth = Integer.parseInt(aucend.substring(3, 5)) - 1;
Integer timeYear = Integer.parseInt(aucend.substring(6, 10));

Time future = new Time();
future.set(timeSecond, timeMinute, timeHour, timeDay, timeMonth, timeYear);
future.normalize(true);
Long futureMillis = future.toMillis(true);

Long interval = futureMillis - nowMillis;

periods.add(interval);              
Durations.add(holder.duration);
total = total + 1 ;
```

I am trying to insert the `holder.duration` into `ArrayList<TextView> Durations`, so I could manage it using one countdowntimer, using this

```
Durations.add(holder.duration);
```

This cause a null pointer exception. The same thing also happens to arraylist period. Why did this happen?

the arraylist used to store those is initialized outside

```
public ArrayList<TextView> Durations;
public ArrayList<Long> periods;
```

Comment: Did you initialize those arrayList?

Comment: oh god, i forgot declaring is not initializing. sorry >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize the ArrayList instances somewhere before you can actually add values to it like this

```
public ArrayList<TextView> Durations = new ArrayList<TextView>();
public ArrayList<Long> periods = new ArrayList<Long>();
```

Directly from the documentation,

*When NullPointerException is thrown?*

> Thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required. These include:

- Calling the instance method of a null object.
- Accessing or modifying the field of a null object. Taking the length of null as if it were an array.
- Accessing or modifying the slots of null as if it were an
  array.
- Throwing null as if it were a Throwable value.

Comment: You are welcome, hope it helps! bless you. Please accept the answer to let others know it worked and closed.

Answer (score 1):

This happened with me when i didn't initialize the arrayList.
try this...

```
public ArrayList<TextView> Durations = new ArrayList<TextView>();
public ArrayList<Long> periods = new ArrayList<Long>();
```

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
public ArrayList<TextView> Durations= new ArrayList<TextView>() ;
public ArrayList<Long> periods=new ArrayList<Long>();
```

Even after that I don't think it's a good approach as in `getView` get called every time view is displayed and `ListView` reuses it's Views so same `TextView` reference will be used for multiple Items.

You can edit your question and tell us what is use of following likes:

```
periods.add(interval);              
Durations.add(holder.duration);
total = total + 1 ;
```

Comment: I actually uses it to centrallize my countdown timer, for the auction. [This is the previous problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368723/android-countdowntimer-in-listview-flickers-randomly/21370921?noredirect=1#comment32227500_21370921), it's solved now, thanks!